# Skip csv header during loading data in clickhouse

Tags: csv, clickhouse

I have a csv file with a header. Is there an option to **clickhouse-client** in order to skip header during inserting data in clickhouse db ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is a format called `CSVWithNames` with which during parsing, both the first and **second** rows are completely ignored.

Comment: Is there a similar one for outputting (e.g. a `SELECT ... format CSV`)  with headers?

Comment: `CSVWithNames` can be used in output.